# i am getting this error . any idea how can i remove this .Creating default object from empty value laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

what i am trying to do is that user can send message to another message so far what i have done is ..
i have created a model named Message and i have defined in model such as

```
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Message extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable= ['sender_id',
    'receiver_id','message',
];
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
}
```

i have defined a realtionship in user model such as

```
public function Message()
      {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class,'receiver_id');
      }
```

i have created an migration of message such as

```
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('sender_id');
            $table->integer('receiver_id');
            $table->string('message');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

what i am trying to do is that user can be able to send a message to another user 
in my message controller i have defined such as

```
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        //dd($request->all());
        $message=new Message();
        $message ->fill($request->all());
        $mesaage->sender_id=Auth::id();
        $message->save();
        return redirect('user');

    }
```

where request->all() is getting all the information which is filled in the form 
the code in my form is such as

```
    <form method="POST" action="{{route('Message.store')}}">
                @csrf   
                        <i class="icon-material-outline-account-circle">{{auth::user()->name}}</i>

                    <textarea name="textarea" cols="10" placeholder="Message" class="with-border"></textarea>
                    <input type="hidden" name="receiver_id" id="receiver_id" value="{{$user->id}}">
                <!-- Button -->
                <button class="button margin-top-35 full-width button-sliding-icon ripple-effect" type="submit">Make an Offer <i class="icon-material-outline-arrow-right-alt"></i></button>
            </form>
            </div>
```

i am getting an error at this line which says that 
$mesaage->sender_id=Auth::id();
Creating default object from empty value

where my user is logged in ..

Comment: Typo: `$mesaage`...

Answer (score 0):

I thing the problem is that your $message object is null:

Maybe you should try another approach:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Message::create($request->all() + ['sender_id' => auth()->id()]);

        return redirect('user');
    }
```